# PinoroEnviro+ TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I have been trying to understand the error reported when I run an example supplied with some hardware i purchased.

I have tried googling around but every answer I get is a bit beyond my comprehension. I think what is going wrong is that the script, or one of the imported scripts is written for Python 2 and i am trying to run it in python 3. 
When I try and run it in Python 2 i get a whole host of other problems so I have been trying to make it work with 3.

The hardware I purchased is the Enviro+ sensor suite for the raspberry pi sold by Pimoroni

[Hardware Link](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/enviro-plus)

[Github Library](https://github.com/pimoroni/enviroplus-python)

[Pimoroni  Tutorial](https://learn.pimoroni.com/tutorial/sandyj/getting-started-with-enviro-plus)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import colorsys
import os
import sys
import ST7735
import ltr559

from bme280 import BME280
from pms5003 import PMS5003
from enviroplus import gas
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

print("""all-in-one.py - Displays readings from all of Enviro plus' sensors

Press Ctrl+C to exit!

""")

# BME280 temperature/pressure/humidity sensor
bme280 = BME280()

# PMS5003 particulate sensor
pms5003 = PMS5003()

# Create ST7735 LCD display class
st7735 = ST7735.ST7735(
    port=0,
    cs=1,
    dc=9,
    backlight=12,
    rotation=270,
    spi_speed_hz=10000000
)

# Initialize display
st7735.begin()

WIDTH = st7735.width
HEIGHT = st7735.height

# Set up canvas and font
img = Image.new('RGB', (WIDTH, HEIGHT), color=(0, 0, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
font = ImageFont.truetype(path + "/fonts/Asap/Asap-Bold.ttf", 20)

message = ""

# The position of the top bar
top_pos = 25


# Displays data and text on the 0.96" LCD
def display_text(variable, data, unit):
    # Maintain length of list
    values[variable] = values[variable][1:] + [data]
    # Scale the values for the variable between 0 and 1
    colours = [(v - min(values[variable]) + 1) / (max(values[variable])
               - min(values[variable]) + 1) for v in values[variable]]
    # Format the variable name and value
    message = "{}: {:.1f} {}".format(variable[:4], data, unit)
    print(message)
    draw.rectangle((0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT), (255, 255, 255))
    for i in range(len(colours)):
        # Convert the values to colours from red to blue
        colour = (1.0 - colours[i]) * 0.6
        r, g, b = [int(x * 255.0) for x in colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(colour,
                   1.0, 1.0)]
        # Draw a 1-pixel wide rectangle of colour
        draw.rectangle((i, top_pos, i+1, HEIGHT), (r, g, b))
        # Draw a line graph in black
        line_y = HEIGHT - (top_pos + (colours[i] * (HEIGHT - top_pos)))\
                 + top_pos
        draw.rectangle((i, line_y, i+1, line_y+1), (0, 0, 0))
    # Write the text at the top in black
    draw.text((0, 0), message, font=font, fill=(0, 0, 0))
    st7735.display(img)


# Get the temperature of the CPU for compensation
def get_cpu_temperature():
    process = Popen(['vcgencmd', 'measure_temp'], stdout=PIPE)
    output, _error = process.communicate()
    return float(output[output.index('=') + 1:output.rindex("'")])


# Tuning factor for compensation. Decrease this number to adjust the
# temperature down, and increase to adjust up
factor = 0.8

cpu_temps = [0] * 5

delay = 0.5  # Debounce the proximity tap
mode = 0  # The starting mode
last_page = 0
light = 1

# Create a values dict to store the data
variables = ["temperature",
             "pressure",
             "humidity",
             "light",
             "oxidised",
             "reduced",
             "nh3",
             "pm1",
             "pm25",
             "pm10"]

values = {}

for v in variables:
    values[v] = [1] * WIDTH

# The main loop
try:
    while True:
        proximity = ltr559.get_proximity()

        # If the proximity crosses the threshold, toggle the mode
        if proximity > 1500 and time.time() - last_page > delay:
            mode += 1
            mode %= len(variables)
            last_page = time.time()

        # One mode for each variable
        if mode == 0:
            variable = "temperature"
            unit = "C"
            cpu_temp = get_cpu_temperature()
            # Smooth out with some averaging to decrease jitter
            cpu_temps = cpu_temps[1:] + [cpu_temp]
            avg_cpu_temp = sum(cpu_temps) / float(len(cpu_temps))
            raw_temp = bme280.get_temperature()
            data = raw_temp - ((avg_cpu_temp - raw_temp) / factor)
            display_text(variable, data, unit)

        if mode == 1:
            variable = "pressure"
            unit = "hPa"
            data = bme280.get_pressure()
            display_text(variable, data, unit)

        if mode == 2:
            variable = "humidity"
            unit = "%"
            data = bme280.get_humidity()
            display_text(variable, data, unit)

        if mode == 3:
            variable = "light"
            unit = "Lux"
            if proximity < 10:
                data = ltr559.get_lux()
            else:
                data = 1
            display_text(variable, data, unit)

        if mode == 4:
            variable = "oxidised"
            unit = "kO"
            data = gas.read_all()
            data = data.oxidising / 1000
            display_text(variable, data, unit)

        if mode == 5:
            variable = "reduced"
            unit = "kO"
            data = gas.read_all()
            data = data.reducing / 1000
            display_text(variable, data, unit)

        if mode == 6:
            variable = "nh3"
            unit = "kO"
            data = gas.read_all()
            data = data.nh3 / 1000
            display_text(variable, data, unit)

        if mode == 7:
            variable = "pm1"
            unit = "ug/m3"
            data = pms5003.read()
            data = data.pm_ug_per_m3(1.0)
            display_text(variable, data, unit)

        if mode == 8:
            variable = "pm25"
            unit = "ug/m3"
            data = pms5003.read()
            data = data.pm_ug_per_m3(2.5)
            display_text(variable, data, unit)

        if mode == 9:
            variable = "pm10"
            unit = "ug/m3"
            data = pms5003.read()
            data = data.pm_ug_per_m3(10)
            display_text(variable, data, unit)

# Exit cleanly
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit(0)
```

When I try and run the code i get the following results:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "all-in-one.py", line 135, in <module>
    cpu_temp = get_cpu_temperature()
  File "all-in-one.py", line 89, in get_cpu_temperature
    return float(output[output.index('=') + 1:output.rindex("'")])
TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'
```

Please forgive me if I have not filled this help request out correctly - i am very new to forums (I hardly ever post in them, although i read them a lot for help), and i am also very new to Python and Linux.

Any help and support from the community would be massively appreciated - thank you in advance...

SW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Python 3 [whitepages on subprocess.communicate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate), the type of `output` and `_error` can be either strings (what you want) ***OR*** bytes. If you were getting strings back, you wouldn't have this problem, but the `TypeError` message you're getting is exactly what you get when you try to call `index()` on a `bytes` object with a string argument.

Demonstrably:

```py
>>> output = "temperature = '88 C'".encode('utf-8') #this is of type bytes
>>> output
b"temperature = '88 C'"
>>> output.index('=')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'
>>> output.index(ord('='))
12
```

So you should replace `output.index('=')` with `output.index(ord('='))` and `output.rindex("'")` with `output.rindex(ord("'"))`.

**EDIT**

I realized this much later, but you can circumvent using `ord()` by prepending your search string with a `b`.

```
output.index(b'=')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help with this as well as including the link to the white paper - I had not come across it in my googling, but I have bookmarked it for reference. I am also very grateful for your help with the solution!! Thank you!